# PHP get 31 days distance from starting date

Tags: php, date, get, days

How can I get what date it will be after 31 days starting with $startDate, where $startDate is a string of this format: YYYYMMDD.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`strtotime` will give you a Unix timestamp:

```
$date = '20101007';
$newDate = strtotime($date.' + 31 days');
```

you can then use `date` to format that into the same format, if that's what you need:

```
echo date('Ymd', $newDate);
```

Comment: Thank you, Tim. Is that the "best" way of doing this? I'm a bit worried about the `+31 days` part.

Comment: You just need to be conscious of what format `$date` is in; if you keep it in a standard format, you're fine - if you try to parse arbitrary formats (eg dd/mm/yyyy vs mm/dd/yyyy) you could run into problems.  Pick one, make sure it works, and then enforce that format for all dates you use.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using PHP 5.3:

```
$date = new DateTime('20101007');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P31D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

The pre-5.3 date functions are lacking, to say the least. The DateTime stuff makes it much easier to deal with dates. https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Comment: Needs one more ')' at end of $date->add(new DateInterval('P31D'));

Answer (score 1):

Just a note that +1 month will also work if you want the same date on the next month and not 31 days exactly each time.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo date('Y m d',strtotime('+31 Days'));
```